# How do I use Go-kit to build microservices and do I need to bring in Gin to use them together?

Tags: rpc, grpc-go

I've been learning to use Go to build a microservices framework, and before that I learned to use Gin to build web services. gin's routing and middleware features I think are very powerful, but Go-kit doesn't seem to have them, or I don't know? Can they be used together?

Also, I've used Java's Springboot and SpringCloud before, is there an equivalent technology in Go language? If Gin is equal to Springboot, is Go-kit equal to SpringCloud.

Thank you!

Do you have any other knowledge, please let me know, I want to know how microservices frameworks are constructed for general implementation in the enterprise.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I think your keyword must need to add `RPC` or `IPC`

You can find some idea at `https://github.com/go-kit/examples/tree/master/addsvc`

If you want more flexible try Standard library : `https://pkg.go.dev/net/rpc` Cross your microservices

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `Gin` and `Go-kit` together. You can use Gin for handling HTTP requests and middleware, and Go-kit for organizing the micro service architecture and communication between services.

Example -

```
// endpoint.go
package main

import (
    "context"
    "github.com/go-kit/kit/endpoint"
)

type upperCaseRequest struct {
    S string `json:"s"`
}

type upperCaseResponse struct {
    V   string `json:"v"`
    Err string `json:"err,omitempty"`
}

func makeUpperCaseEndpoint(svc StringService) endpoint.Endpoint {
    return func(ctx context.Context, request interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
        req := request.(upperCaseRequest)
        v, err := svc.UpperCase(req.S)
        if err != nil {
            return upperCaseResponse{v, err.Error()}, nil
        }
        return upperCaseResponse{v, ""}, nil
    }
}
```

Set up Gin and integrate it with your Go-kit service:

```
// main.go
package main

import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    httptransport "github.com/go-kit/kit/transport/http"
)

func main() {
    // Create your service instance
    svc := stringService{}

    // Create the Go-kit endpoint
    upperCaseEndpoint := makeUpperCaseEndpoint(svc)

    // Set up the Go-kit HTTP transport
    upperCaseHandler := httptransport.NewServer(
        upperCaseEndpoint,
        decodeUpperCaseRequest,
        encodeResponse,
    )

    // Set up Gin
    router := gin.Default()

    // Register your endpoint with Gin
    router.POST("/uppercase", gin.WrapH(upperCaseHandler))

    // Start the Gin server
    router.Run(":8080")
}

func decodeUpperCaseRequest(_ context.Context, r *http.Request) (interface{}, error) {
    var req upperCaseRequest
    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&req)
    return req, err
}

func encodeResponse(_ context.Context, w http.ResponseWriter, response interface{}) error {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
    return json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(response)
}
```

This is very simplified version of the code. Just to demonstrate.

Regarding your question about SpringBoot and SpringCloud equivalents in Go:

Gin can be considered equivalent to SpringBoot as it's a web framework used for creating web services, handling routing, and middleware.

Go-kit can be considered equivalent to SpringCloud, as it's a toolkit for building microservices and handling communication between them.

In addition to Go-kit, there are other microservices frameworks and libraries available in Go, such as:

Micro: A microservices development framework that provides service discovery, load balancing, and more.

gRPC: A high-performance RPC framework that supports service definitions using Protocol Buffers and allows for efficient communication